# What should I use in Mysqli bind_param() i or s

Tags: php, mysqli

I have numbers/digits and characters too in string. I want to insert it into database using mysqli `bind_param('s', $string)`. Is it okay or I have to use si both or what?

Comment: If it is string then it is ok.

Comment: Nope `bind_param(s` `<-----`problem is over here need quotes around it @b0s3

Comment: @Uchiha I'm already using `bind_param('s'` but not mentioned here. I have updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is okay.

If you bind the parameter as int:

```
$stmt->bind_param('i', $bar);
```

Then the query will be about equivalent to:

```
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (42)
```

However, if you bind as string:

```
$stmt->bind_param('s', $bar);
```

The query will be about equivalent to:

```
INSERT INTO foo VALUES ('42')
```

Answer (score 0):

A sequence of characters that contains both letters and digits is a string. You should use `s` for it.